# .NET Core 6 Dependency Injection: Class with User

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I'm struggling to fully understand how I use DI properly for certain things. All my razor pages need to check various permissions via the user's claims. I have a permissions manager class that handles this for me, but I'm constructing that class on every page at the moment. I'm sure that I must be able to inject that class from the start-up so it's just available to use. The trouble is, the class constructor takes the ClaimsPrincipal as a parameter e.g.

```
var permissionManager = new PermissionManager(User);
```

Can I inject such a class from the start-up if I make it implement an Interface?

Answer (score 1):

Make `PermissionManager` a "regular" injectable class by providing a DI interface ("`IPermissionManager`"), removing User from the constructor, and adding `IHttpContextAccessor` as constructor parameter instead.

With `IHttpContextAccessor` you can access the User with `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User`.

After that you can inject `IPermissionManager` where you need it instead of creating it using `new` (as long as you have registered it in some way).

Note; you also need to `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in your Startup.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to work around this issue but you can't meaningfully inject this class via DI as is. Here are at least some possibilities:

1. replace `User` ctor parameter with `IHttpContextAccessor` ([access `HttpContext` in `ASP.NET Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) one and use [`HttpContext.User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property internally
2. remove `User` ctor parameter and add `User` parameter to corresponding methods of `PermissionManager`
3. create and inject a factory returning permission manager for concrete user.

Also I would recommend to abstract `PermissionManager` via interface (for example `IPermissionManager`) and use interface for registration and resolving.